# Can't link my css file in my django project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">This is the Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py (my app name is base)

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testpro.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testpro.wsgi.application'

...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = BASE_DIR, 'static'
```

Folder structure is like this:

```
project folder
    /static
       /style.css
```

CSS contains a simple color change and it is not working.

I've tried linking the css file in different ways and nothing seems to be working. I don't know how or why but sometimes it suddenly works and then suddenly stops working.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the

```
<head>
<link href="{%static 'style.css'%}" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>
```

and
add this to the testpro (urls.py)

```
from testpro import settings

urlpatterns = [
// here goes your urls 
]
//at the bottom add this
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

and in the settings.py
change

```
STATICFILES_DIRS= BASE_DIR, 'static' to
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

Comment: i didn't really get what you mean by adding this line urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS) it doesn't recognize the words static and settings should i import something ? and where exactly should i write this line, under my urlpatterns ?

Comment: I have edited the code above , hope this helps

Comment: my VS code does not recognize the word static in the line you mentioned

Comment: This is complitley wrong i can't import such thing even before trying that, that does not make any sense to import such thing (i tried it and im right the import line is incorrect)

Comment: My bad! its:::: from django.conf.urls.static import static

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = BASE_DIR, 'static'
```

Try this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Comment: i tried that before its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to specify base directory in templates array.**

```
DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
```

Just let it be empty.

```
DIRS': [],
```

and all other looks fine just make sure about CSS files. and it's location.

Comment: i have to specify it otherwise it wont recognize my templates, anyway i tried that and it comes up with an error

Comment: Django will search for templates inside the templates directory by default. but in your case, I don't know the version and other things of your project.

May be this will Help.

https://www.csestack.org/add-css-static-files-django/#:~:text=%E2%94%80%E2%94%80registration-,Including%20CSS%20in%20Django%20Template,HTML)%20file.&text=Then%2C%20insert%20the%20stylesheet%20in%20the%20HTML%20using%20link%20HTML%20tag.&text=If%20you%20are%20new%20to,adding%20CSS%20in%20HTML%20code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the `settings.py` to something like this:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<Your APP name goes here>\static'),)
```

If you have an 'css' subfolder inside your static folder then you need to add that to the relative path in your HTML template like this:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">This is the Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that helps you!